# how to allow user to take backup of database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am building project using **asp.net and sql server**. 
It is 3 tier application. I want to give facility for the admin user to take backup of the database. the **database should be downloadable from browser**.
for this i was using backup query in sql server. which places the backup of the database at server side and then user was able to download .BAK file from the link.
But when size of the database crosses about 1/2 GB "**timeout exception**" was occurring and backup was not created at the server side. I had increased timeout period in connection string, but did'nt worked.
I dont want scheduled backup. Backup should be created when the user wants and **backup should be downloadable by the user**.

Guys please help me out.. And thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your code that created the backup. But why use the browser as  transfer means ?

Comment: It is easy. Not secure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a similar application in the past.  My approach was to create a SQL job to do the backup.  It doesn't need to be placed on a recurring schedule.

The web page simply starts the job by calling `sp_start_job @job_name = 'MyBackupJob'`.  This is asynchronous, so there won't be any timeout issues.
Since the job can not run concurrently, it also keeps multiple people from running a backup at the same time.

Then using either a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx) control or a javascript/web service based approach, poll for the status of the job.

When the job is no longer running - provide the link to download.

Here's the methods I used to start/check the job.

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Starts the SQL Server job.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="jobName">Name of the job.</param>
    ''' <param name="connectionString">The connection string.</param>
    ''' <remarks>No exception handling is done.  Assumes connection has access to msdb</remarks>
    Public Sub StartJob(ByVal jobName As String, ByVal connectionString As String)

        Using dbConn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Using dbCmd As New SqlCommand("msdb.dbo.sp_start_job", dbConn)
                dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_name", jobName)
                dbConn.Open()
                dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                dbConn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines whether [is job running] [the specified job name].
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="jobName">Name of the job.</param>
    ''' <param name="connectionString">The connection string.</param>
    ''' <returns>
    ''' <c>true</c> if [is job running] [the specified job name]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    ''' </returns>
    ''' <remarks>No exception handling is done.  Assumes connection has access to msdb</remarks>
    Public Function IsJobRunning(ByVal jobName As String, ByVal connectionString As String) As Boolean

        Using dbConn As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
            Using dbCmd As New SqlCommand("msdb.dbo.sp_help_job", dbConn)
                dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_name", jobName)
                dbConn.Open()
                Dim dr As SqlDataReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader()
                Dim stat As Integer
                If dr.Read() Then
                    stat = Convert.ToInt16(dr("current_execution_status"))
                Else
                    stat = -1
                End If

                dr.Close()
                dbConn.Close()
                If stat = 1 Then
                    Return True
                Else
                    Return False
                End If
            End Using
        End Using 
    End Function
```

You could go one step further and check if the job completed successfully by inspecting the value of last_run_outcome in  `msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @job_name ='MyBackupJob'`

You can get the backup file name by running this query:

```
SELECT TOP 1   mf.physical_device_name FROM msdb.dbo.backupset AS s 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediaset AS ms ON s.media_set_id = ms.media_set_id
INNER JOIN  msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily AS mf ON ms.media_set_id = mf.media_set_id
WHERE  s.database_name = N'YourDatabaseName' 
ORDER BY  s.backup_finish_date DESC;
```